# std::function as a custom stream manipulator

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, iostream, manipulators

I'm trying to use C++11 features to make custom stream manipulators easier to create.  I can use lambda functions as manipulators, but not `std::function<ostream&(ostream&)>`.

Here's the code, boiled down:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

auto lambdaManip = [] (ostream& stream) -> ostream& {
    stream << "Hello world" << endl;
};
function<ostream& (ostream&)> functionManip = [] (ostream& stream) -> ostream& {
    stream << "Hello world" << endl;
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << lambdaManip;    // OK
    cout << functionManip;  // Compiler error
}
```

The second `cout` statement fails with the following:

```
g++-4 src/Solve.cpp -c -g -std=c++0x -o src/Solve.o -I/home/ekrohne/minisat
src/Solve.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
src/Solve.cpp:24:11: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/ostream:579:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Tp = std::function<std::basic_ostream<char>&(std::basic_ostream<char>&)>]'
```

Why does this fail?  I'm using cygwin gcc 4.5.3.

While I'm asking, I'm not nuts about using `std::function` everywhere, due to the efficiency problems.  But I do wish to write functions that return lambda functions, and have no idea how to do so without `std::function`.  For example, something like the following would be great

```
auto getAdditionFunctor();

auto getAdditionFunctor() {
    return [] (int x, int y) { return x + y };
};
```

...but obviously does not work. Is there an alternate syntax that does work?  I can't imagine what it could be, so I may be stuck with `std::function`.

If I had a solution to the second question, then the first question would be moot.

---

Thank you.

Defining `operator<<(ostream&, std::function<ostream&(ostream&)>` helped.  I had misread a web page, and was under the impression that `ostream` was smart enough to treat an arbitrary object that had an `operator()` as a manipulator.  I was wrong about this.  Furthermore, the simple `lambda` I built was probably just getting compiled into a plain old function, just as I was told.  Indeed, if I use variable capture to ensure that the `lambda` is not a simple function, then the compiler fails.  Also, objects with `operator()` defined are not (by default) treated as manipulators:

```
class Manipulator {
    ostream& operator()(ostream& stream) const {
        return stream << "Hello world" << endl;
    };
} classManip;

function<ostream& (ostream&)> functionManip = [] (ostream& stream) -> ostream& {
    return stream << "Hello world" << endl;
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    const string str = "Hello world"; 
    auto lambdaManip = [&] (ostream& stream) -> ostream& {
        return stream << str << endl;     
    };

    cout << classManip;     // Compiler error
    cout << lambdaManip;    // Compiler error
    cout << functionManip;  // Compiler error
}
```

---

Further update: it turns out a slightly more robust solution than the ones below can be accomplished with:

```
// Tell ostreams to interpret std::function as a
// manipulator, wherever it sees one.
inline ostream& operator<<(
        ostream& stream, 
        const function<ostream& (ostream&)>& manipulator) {
    return manipulator( stream );
}
```

This code has an extra `const`.  I discovered this trying to actually implement the solution in my project.

Comment: Did you mean to leave out a 'return' in those manipulators?

Comment: I had read that those are implied, and adding them doesn't help.  In this case I think they're more readable with the returns, but they're legal without.  After all, everything works works fine if I comment out `cout << functionManip;`.

Comment: @EdKrohne : `return` is **not** optional here – your lambdas invoke UB by having a non-`void` return type and not returning a value, just as with any other function. §6.6.3/2: "*Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.*" Appearing to work fine is merely one possible manifestation of UB.

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you.  Again had misread a web site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `operator<<` for `ostream`, there's no overload for taking a `std::function` - and that's basically what you're trying to do here with `cout << functionManip`. To fix this, either define the overload yourself:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, std::function<ostream& (ostream&)>& s)
{
    return s(os);
}
```

Or pass the `stream` as an argument to the function:

```
functionManip(std::cout);
```

As for why the `lambda` is working, given that the return type of a `lambda` is undefined, and there is an overload for using a function pointer:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& ( *pf )(ostream&));
```

The lambda is probably wrapping everything utilizing a a struct and defining `operator()` which in this case will work exactly like a function pointer. This to me is the most likely explanation, hopefully someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The behavior isn't accidental, it's mandated by the Standard. A lambda that doesn't capture anything is *always* implicitly convertible to a plain old function pointer. (And inversely: a lambda that *does* capture anything is *never* implicitly convertible to a function pointer.)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the cause of the error, but since you've defined both `lambdaManip` and `functionManip` as having the return type `ostream&` I believe you've forgotten to add `return stream;` to both.

---

The call `cout << functionManip` fails because there is no `operator<<(ostream&, std::function<ostream&(ostream&)>` defined. Add one and the call will succeed.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, function<ostream& (ostream&)>& func) {
  return func( stream );
}
```

Alternatively, you can call `functionManip` as

```
functionManip( cout );
```

This will work without adding the `operator<<` definition.

---

As for your question about returning a lambda, since the lambda returned by `getAdditionFunctor` is a capture-less lambda, it can be implicitly converted to a function pointer.

```
typedef int(*addition_ptr)(int,int);
addition_ptr getAdditionFunctor()
{
  return [] (int x, int y) -> int { return x + y; };
}

auto adder = getAdditionFunctor();
adder(10,20); // Outputs 30
```

Comment: Good point, I should have thought about that for my toy example. But what if I'm capturing?  Variable capture is the point of returning a `lambda` from a function; if I didn't want to do variable capture, I'd just use a plain old function in the first place.

Comment: +1. I didn't know capture-less lambdas were implicitly convertible to function pointers, but it make perfect sense.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers got the state of the art right, but if you are going to be *heavily* using `std::function`s and/or lambdas as stream manipulators in your code, then you might just want to add the following function template definition to your codebase, at global scope:

```
template<class M>
auto operator<< (std::ostream& os, const M& m) -> decltype(m(os))
{
    return m(os);
}
```

The trailing return type there uses [expression SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae#Expression_SFINAE), so this particular `operator<<` overload won't even participate in overload resolution unless `m(os)` is a well-formed expression. (This is what you want.)

Then you can even do things like

```
template<class T>
auto commaize(const T& t)
{
    return [&t](std::ostream& os) -> std::ostream& {
        return os << t << ", ";
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << commaize("hello") << commaize("darling") << std::endl;
}
```

(Notice the total lack of any `std::function` objects in the above code! Try to avoid stuffing lambdas into `std::function` objects unless you absolutely have to, because constructing a `std::function` object can be expensive; it can even involve memory allocation.)

It would make sense for C++17 to add this `operator<<` overload to the standard library, but I'm not aware of any concrete proposals in that area at the moment.

Comment: I think I found the reason, why it is not in the standard... o.O (or I messed up, which is always also possible...). I placed the template operator<< right after #include <iostream> into a project-global header and from then on, it seemed to try take over all operator<<() functions in the project. (clang++-13, debian linux, -std=c++20). So I guess the "expression SFINAE" is not really working (anymore?!).

Comment: @BitTickler: Expression SFINAE has issues in old versions of MSVC, but that's all. I suspect you've got a bug somewhere. If you post a godbolt.org link (like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jea3ed5da) but with your broken code), I could take a look.

Comment: Sorry - cannot reproduce that in canonical example. I wanted to make progress in another direction and so I kicked this approach at first signs of trouble.